# How do I convert a switch’s single output into a double output per keypress?

Tags: arduino, switches, output, input, mechanical

I am new to electronics compared to many here I’m sure, but I have some experience with Arduinos and basic circuits and PCBs. If for example I had two mechanical keyboard switches wired up to an Arduino board (one ground wire and two for the signals), and they are designed to trigger only once upon a keypress, how can I wire them and to what in what way so that at any time I can convert their signals to double their usual output and cause the signal to trigger twice rapidly per keypress (or more)? I have read about different switches such as SPST, DPDT, etc, but if that is the kind of stuff that is needed I am not entirely sure how to apply that. Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *wire* them that way - the switch is designed to make contact exactly once.

However, you don't have to - you have a microcontroller that can be programmed to do anything when it sees that single impulse, including, for example, pulling an output pin low twice.

Comment: I suppose then I need to take that to the Arduino community. Thanks.